# Can a Facebook app collect a user’s Timeline images and details?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

Is it possible for a Facebook app to collect a user’s Timeline images and a few of the user’s details?

I am asking as I would like to have an app made that makes use of the user’s timeline images (present and past), like Moo.com Facebook business cards.

Comment: Depends on tho code you write.. When an app can return user's profile pic,it can also pick his timeline pic

Answer (score 1):

in short, Yes.The app can get the user's information via API but depends only on what kind of access that the user granted to the app.

I suggest you should explore more those information (like Graph API, Opengraph API from facebook) on Facebook developer websites.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/keyconcepts/#actions-objects

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/